# Trying to block authentication if user is in the banned collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am building a chat app and I am trying to figure out the banning system. The idea if the user is in the banned collection becaused he used banned words, block authentication from his account. The problem is that for some reason it does execute the code but rather only does the signInWithRedirect() function. Take a look at my code:

```
const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await signInWithRedirect(auth, googleProvider);
    const user = res.user;
    const q = query(collection(db, "banned"), where("uid", "==", user.uid));
    const docs = await getDocs(q);
    if (docs.exists()) {
    //if exists ban the user
    console.log('you cannot use this chat app , you are banned!)
```

Here is also the LoginPage.jsx

```
function LoginPage() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth)
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  console.log(user)

  return (
    <div>
        <div style={{'display': 'none'}}>
          <Navbar />
        </div>
        <Welcome  />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is also signOut

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
  const signOutWithGoogle = () => {
    signOut(auth)
     navigate('/')
  }
```

[Here is firebase firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8aYs.png)

I tried this with promises but nothing happened , I used async , nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

I would not implement such a "banning" system only based on front-end code. It would actually be quite easy for a malicious end-user to bypass your check based on a standard query to a collection.

I would use a [Firebase Security Rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) to enforce the banishment: Security Rules stand between your data and malicious users and are executed/checked in the back-end. To be complete, with this approach the user will still be authenticated and signed-in but will not be able to interact with the Firebase back-end services like Firestore or Cloud Storage.

Concretely you could as follows:

1. Write a security rule based on a specific collection in which you create a document per banned user with the user ID as document ID. Then you can use the [`exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) method to check if the user is banned or not.
2. Use a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to ban (and maybe "un-ban") a user. Again, with Cloud Function the code is executed in the back-end and you therefore avoid the possibility that a malicious user writes a code that could "un-ban" him.